# emulator with OpenGL ES 2 support on AMD CPU

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, gpu, amd-processor

I started developing with OpenGL ES 2 for android some time ago, but until now I'm not able to use the official android emulator to test my applications. I know, the emulator supports hardware acceleration and OpenGL ES 2, but both seems to be limited to Intel CPUs on windows.
Does anyone know a solution, how to get OpenGL working on my computer? 
Using my smartphone is possible, but I have to use my personal phone and don't have a device dedicated for developing and testing purpose.

My PC:
CPU: Amd Phenom II 955
GPU: Nvidia Geforce GTX 660
OS: Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Android AVDs with accelerated OpenGL ES emulation does work on AMD processors but you might have to create an ARM AVD, instead of an X86 AVD.  Either way, the OpenGL ES emulation can still be accelerated if you have an Nvidia or AMD card in your PC with good OpenGL drivers.

What certainly does not work is using Intel's HAXM native emulation because that requires the Virtualization Technology feature that only newer Intel processors have.

This article[1](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-2) should help:

Comment: Unfortunately, ARM emulation is horrible slow. Also I don't get GLES2 support in the emulator, even with hardware GPU acceleration enabled.

At work using an AMD CPU with linux, hardware acceleration works perfect, so I don't understand, why Intel is required with windows, but not with linux.